# Write line of code into div with onclick

Tags: javascript, html

I want a javascript to write a specific line of code into my div, to activate a link, when a button is pressed at a specific date.

Javascript:

```
function todaydate() {
    var d=new Date();
    d.setDate("Oktober 29, 2016")
    document.getElementById('Vign1').innerHTML ="<a href="layout.php">";
}
```

Html for the Button:

```
<div id="Vign1">
 <button onclick="todaydate();">    
 </button>
 </a>
 </div>
```

So the idea was, that if the button is clicked at f.e. 29 October, 2016, my javascript adds the line of code to complete the link and activate it. Can someone help me, why it doesn't work?

EDIT:

The date check doesn't work. Can anyone help here? It should only be activated on or after an specific date. But it won't work..
My current code:

```
function todaydate() {
var submitDate = new Date();
var oct30 = new Date("October 30, 2016 00:25:00 ");
if (oct30.getTime() == submitDate.getTime()) {

  document.getElementById('link').setAttribute('href', 'layout.php');
}
else if (oct30.getTime() != submitDate.getTime()) {
document.getElementById('link').setAttribute('href', 'nichtverfuegbar.php');

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Several issues here:

```
document.getElementById('Vign1').innerHTML ="<a href="layout.php">";
```

That's not going to work because you've got double-quotes nested in your html string. Would have to be this:

```
document.getElementById('Vign1').innerHTML ="<a href='layout.php'>";
```

However, that's also not what you want. That will overwrite all the html in the div with just that opening tag, including the button, the closing tag, etc.

Also, your link as you're trying to write it would have no text in it - how would anyone see anything to click?

Here's one approach. (You could also just have the onclick function add the entire link as an element, if that works better for your use case.) Note - you still don't have any actual date-checking logic written. I'm assuming you're going to get to that next. Until that's added, this button will always create a link.

```js
function todaydate() {
  var d = new Date();
  d.setDate("Oktober 29, 2016")

  document.getElementById('link').setAttribute('href', 'layout.php');

  // optional, for demo purposes
  document.getElementById('link').innerText = 'A link!';
}
```

```html
<div id="Vign1">
  <button onclick="todaydate();">Click me!
  </button>
  <a id="link">Not a link</a>
</div>
```

Comment: That's nice! Thank you!! But what do I do, when the <a id="link">Not a link</a> is another button who should get activated and link to another page?

Comment: I solved the button problem. But now another question - is the activation only on Oktober 29 possible? Or even after? Because I can set any date and it gets activated, if I click the button..

Comment: That's definitely possible - try searching "javascript after date" and you'll come up with some good examples. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17350586/javascript-set-hidden-field-if-date-after-jan-15) should point you in the right direction.